# How to change this Gradle config to Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Now I try to use Gradle Kotlin Dsl instead of the Gradle.But I can not convert these configurations.

I can not find some example on the github.

```
// build.gradle
task annotationProcessing(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') { // codegen
  source = sourceSets.main.java
  classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.compileOnly
  destinationDir = project.file('src/main/generated')
  options.compilerArgs = [
    "-proc:only",
    "-processor", "io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor",
    "-Acodegen.output=${project.projectDir}/src/main"
  ]
}

compileJava {
  targetCompatibility = 1.8
  sourceCompatibility = 1.8

  dependsOn annotationProcessing
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs += 'src/main/generated'
    }
  }
}
```

How to convert these configurations?

Thanks!

Comment: What about using that: https://github.com/bernaferrari/GradleKotlinConverter

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough I've struggled with the same problem this morning.

I managed to convert it so that the Gradle Kotlin interpreter doesn't complain anymore. But I still get an error stating "Annotation processor 'io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor' not found when I build the project with `gradle run`.

Nevertheless, here is the converted snippet:

```
tasks {
  register<JavaCompile>("annotationProcessing") {
    group = "build"
    source = sourceSets.main.get().java
    classpath = configurations.compile.get() + configurations.compileOnly.get()
    destinationDir = project.file("src/main/generated");
    options.compilerArgs = listOf(
      "-proc:only",
      "-processor", "io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor",
      "-Acodegen.output=${project.projectDir}/src/main")
  }

  compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"

    dependsOn(":annotationProcessing")
  }

  sourceSets {
    main {
      java {
        setSrcDirs(srcDirs.plus("src/main/generated"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming you're going through the [A gentle guide to asynchronous programming with Eclipse Vert.x for Java developers](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/) or at least trying to get the code generation of Vert.x services running, I found a different solution to the problem.

Instead of using the "manual" approach of configuring the code generation, you can add the following lines to the "dependencies" definition:

```
dependencies {
  [...]
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion"
  compileOnly("io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion")
  annotationProcessor("io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion")
  annotationProcessor("io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion:processor")
  [...]
}
```

This configuration allowed me to set up the code generation. But there is one difference to the configuration above:

The java classes will be generated directly in the `build/classes/java/...` folder.

I for myself am still trying to figure out the new Gradle Kotlin DSL. So maybe there is an even better approach to this.

Comment: HI,tegri! So thanks! And now ,I try to use `kapt` to generated.

Comment: And Just like you said java classes will be generated directly in the build/classes/java/... folder. I try to some method to change is, but I failed...The strange thing is that the document folder has changed. This is my [build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/gzmuSoft/authorization-center/blob/master/build.gradle.kts). And you can see this doc `authorization-center/authorization-user/src/main/generated/asciidoc/dataobjects.adoc` is in `src/main/generated/asciidoc`. It is so interesting. But the java classes no change...